# Java buildpack for sourceless project?

Tags: elasticsearch, heroku, buildpack

We're wanting to set up Elastic Search with Appbase.io's [abc](https://github.com/appbaseio/abc) tool (pointed at one of our existing PostgreSQL dynos).  We don't want to compile either of these tools, but Heroku's buildpack documentation strongly suggests that there are flags that are set with the java buildpack sets that we want/need.  The most simple solution would probably be to set up an empty pom file, but I don't know if that would actually work.  (I assume it's not that hard to do--no java knowledge here.)

I plan to use [Amiel's fix of the apt buildpack](https://github.com/amiel/heroku-buildpack-apt/tree/feature/support-adding-keys) to actually install Elastic Search, and a custom buildpack to grab & install abc.

1. Is this a reasonable approach?
2. What are the gottchas we need to watch out for?

Comment: That tool appears to be written in Go. What does this have to do with the Java buildpack?

Comment: Elastic Search is going to be the primary executable in the dyno, and that source is 99% java.  Abc is just fabric for ES here.

Comment: I would consider Docker deployment (supported by Heroku) which sets the stack `container` and it is language agnostic

Comment: [Please ask only one question at a time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/248627), and please avoid questions that are primarily opinion-based or open-ended. You can read about what's on-topic in the [help/on-topic].

Comment: Having said that, Beppe C's Docker suggestion is reasonable. There is also an official [JVM buildpack](https://elements.heroku.com/buildpacks/heroku/heroku-buildpack-jvm-common) that ships the JVM but doesn't build an application.